# Mysql retornando todos os inteiros como string no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Sempre que estou fazendo uma consulta, o PHP está trazendo os dados do banco de dados MYSQL como `string`, e isso está afetando a conversão dos dados quando eu envio ao cliente uma resposta JSON.

Por exemplo, na tabela `users` tenho os campos `id`, `name` e `role_id`. Quando eu retorno o JSON desses dados, ao invés de obter:

```
{ "id" : 1, "name": "Wallace", "role_id" : 12 }
```

Estou recebendo:

```
{"id" : "1", "name": "Wallace", "role_id" : "12" }
```

Ou seja, de alguma forma, os dados retornados do MYSQL estão sendo tratados todos como `string`.

Eu poderia fazer um CAST, mas fazer isso toda hora poderia ser um pé-no-saco.

Como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Poderia ser algum problema com o MYSQL ou a extensão do PHP responsável por comunicar com ela?

Veja a estrutura da tabela abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: No PDO tem um flag que força o resultado dos campos a serem sempre strings.

Comment: @rray e tem uma flag que faça o oposto?

Comment: No caso é o `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` dá uma olhada no valor. Se tem o oposto eu não lembro de cabeça.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao fazer a conversão para `JSON` com o `json_encode`, você pode passar o parâmetro `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, ele está disponível a partir da versão `5.3.3`, ele basicamente checa se aquele valor pode ser considerado numérico(acredito que com a função `is_numeric`), e caso seja, apresentará no `JSON` como um.

**Veja estes exemplos:**

Uso comum com valores numéricos:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); //{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Uso com valores em string que podem ser convertidos para tipo numérico.

```
$arr = array('a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3", 'd' => "4", 'e' => "5");
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); //{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Veja mais sobre o `json_encode` na [documentação oficial do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php).

**Usando o driver nativo do MySQL:**

Por padrão, todas as operações entre banco/PHP, retornarão todos os valores numéricos como uma string, para contornar isso no `MySql`, a partir do PHP 5.3.0, você pode usar o [MySQL Native Driver](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqlnd.php), ele é uma extensão do PHP escrita como parte do projeto, onde está sob a licensa do mesmo.

Usando o `mysqlnd` e o `mysqli`, você pode pedir que retorne os valores numéricos com seus tipos corretos passando a seguinte option:

```
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true);
```

Já utilizando o `PDO`, ele automaticamente fará as conversões, mas todas as queries devem ser antes preparadas no server-side.

Você pode ver a comparação entre o `mysqlnd` e o `libmysqlclient` [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php).

Comment: Ótima solução. Porém me pergunto sobre o caso de não estar usando o JSON e tiver que obter os resultados como inteiro. O ideial é que tivesse uma solução para o problema que resolvesse na comunicação entre PHP e MYSQL (dica: PHP mysql native driver :D)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Cara, toda comunicação de seleção entre o php/bd vai transformar valores numéricos em string, pelo fato do php ser dinâmico, geralmente nem vale a pena fazer a conversão. Você poderia sim utilizar o `mysqlnd`, mas talvez não valha a pena a instalação de uma lib quando o problema atual é só para transformar os dados em `JSON`, isso pode ser corrigido no momento do parse.

Comment: Não, não. O JSON na pergunta é só um exemplo. O problema na verdade é do MYSQL.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Você parece saber como faz kk, de qualquer forma adicionei na minha resposta.